# How to check if a div and the results of a php script are different and if so, replace div with results of PHP script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

**Explanation:**

I wrote a PHP script that fetches, parses and echoes XML content. The results of that script are fetched through a jQuery script and put into a div# on my website. That div# is empty(at first) in the html of the website and it's populated by the jQuery script.

The contents of the PHP scripts are news articles. Each article is echoed into a html element with 3 children (article link, title, source).

The jQuery script gets those articles every 60 seconds and refreshes the div on my website with them.

Refreshing the div id every 60 seconds isn't very elegant.

**jQuery script:**

```
     $(document).ready(function getarticles() {
            $.get("/Script.php", function (result) {
                $('#articles').html(result);
            });
        setTimeout(getarticles, 60000);
        })();
```

**How the results of the PHP script are structured**

```
 <articlelink><a href="<?php echo $entries->link['href']; ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="article">
   <article>           
       <articletitle><?php echo $entries->title; ?> </articletitle>
       <articleinfo> - <?php echo $entries->source->title; ?> </articleinfo>    
   </article>
 </a></articlelink>
```

**Question**:

1. How can I compare the contents of the website div with the php script results and only IF they're different will the website div get refreshed?

1.1. It would be enough just to compare the first child of the website div with the first result of the php script and if they're different, just refresh the whole website div. Not very elegant, but the easiest to implement.

1.2. The perfect scenario would be if I could compare all children of the website div and the results of the php script and if they're different, **add** the **difference** between the two to the website div. But this is the more complicated scenario.

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any *"last modified"* data in the xml? How about unique identifiers? Very likely you can do more server side to simplify this update process

Comment: Also what is the actual problem with replacing all the content?

Comment: Articles do indeed have id tags. I could maybe use those to compare articles in JS, but I still don't really know how to do that code-wise. I'm definitely a beginner.

No actual problem with replacing all the content. But thinking ahead, I wanted to maybe implement an animation for newer articles - e.g. once there's a new article the jQuery would add it and push the others down through an animation. No real functionality there, would just look pretty cool.